# Have we discovered constructions for natural fractional dimensional spheres?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, geometric-measure-theory, fractals

I have been thinking about a couple different problems in fractal geometry (including I one deleted because it was ill posed) and realize they all depend in a fundamental way on the problem of: Can we construct a fractional dimensional sphere?

I did some digging online and kept coming up short, there is a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783732/is-a-hypersphere-of-non-integer-dimension-a-fractal) asking about spheres of fractal dimension but unfortunately no explicit discussions about construction take place.

So I wanted to pose the problem here explicitly. We begin with a little bit of setup:

We can define a "n-ball" in 3 different ways I suspect when we consider fractals these three ways will end up becoming inequivalent.

**Strategy 1: Points that are equidistant from a center**

We can always define a ball of radius $\epsilon$ on a set $S$ equipped with a distance function $d$ as the set of all points of distance $\epsilon$ away from some center point $u \in S$. This certainly works and lets you make balls in very abstract settings. But we run into some challenges with this. The "Usual" spheres (the sphere, circle, line segment, etc... ) are defined as balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so to create a canonical sphere we need to be able to generalize $\mathbb{R}^n$ for fractional $n$ and to define that (to the best of my ability) we should know how to construct fractional-dimensional cubes (but to define these cubes we need angles and to define angles we need spheres again). If only there was a way to define fractal $\mathbb{R}^n$ that's natural and doesn't depend on spheres we could then define our spheres on it.

**Strategy 2: Spheres as fractal manifolds**

We can define an $\alpha > 1$  sphere $S$ as a set with a few properties.

1. $S$ has a boundary $\partial S$ is not empty and $\partial^2 S = \emptyset$
2. $S$ has [hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) $\alpha$ and moreover its [hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) should be equal $V_s(d) = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right)} \frac{d^n}{2^n}$ (I'm defining my hausdorff content scaled so that it agrees with lebesgue measure) where $d$ is the diameter of the set (the length of the largest $1$-dimensional line segment we can fit in the set)
3. $S$ is simply connected (I think for $\alpha<1$ this requirement must be dropped)
4. The boundary of $S$ has hausdorff dimension $\alpha-1$ and its hausdorff measure is $2 \frac{\partial}{\partial d} V_s(d)$.

These are very specific requirements and they don't make it obvious what a "construction" looks like for fractional dimensions. And/Or i'm just incompetent with using these tools.

**Strategy 3: Spheres Maximize Their Volume For a Given Boundary**

This is again non constructive (unless we can define a calculus of variations in fractional dimensional space) but the premise is to start with a set $\partial S$ which has a fixed fractal dimension and ask what set should $\partial S$ be so that it is the boundary of a set $S$ and the hausdorff measure of $S$ is maximized.

**The Question:**  Using ANY of these strategies (or your own if you have a better characterization that is easier to generalize) have we been able to define a family of fractional $n$-spheres? Or even just been able to construct ONE such sphere for non positive-integral dimension?

---

It appears that cantor sets have a known hausdorff measure of 1 (I need to see which definition is used but this might re-scale to the desired spherical measures)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between balls and spheres in this question. Normally the term ball is reserved for the set of all points of distance $\leq r$ (or $<r$) from a given center, and sphere is used for points of a fixed distance. You seem to be using both terms and notions interchangeably throughout. For example in your first strategy you are looking at fixed distance, but in your second strategy, since you want the boundary to be nontrivial, you must be thinking of a ball and not of a sphere.

Comment: I'm happy to edit to however you see fit but we often say things like "volume of a sphere" which according to your distinction is wrong and should instead be "volume of a 2-ball" (which i've seen  a lot less but maybe seen a few times nw that i think about it). I tried to express myself in the way that made the most sense to my readers. In either case i'm interested in "q-balls" where $q$ is not necessarily an integer and where the $q$-ball behaves as close to our intuition on euclidean $n$-balls as possible. I'm willing to believe might be more than one way to do this and the approaches

Comment: Preserve different useful characteristics but no one approach might preserve ALL desired characteristics.

Comment: "Volume of a sphere" can be thought of as short for the volume of the region bounded by the sphere, but the sphere itself is still only the boundary.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4687095/2513